# display json from php in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a php file returning this valid Json data, stored in a javascript variable named "json".

```
[
"564654.56464",
"848492.25477",
"918821.54471"
]
```

I try to display it in javascript with :

```
var object = JSON.parse(json);
document.write(object. ..... );
```

i don't know what to add here since my Json is not like   {"attribute":"value","attribute2":"value2"

Comment: printed json and your explanation down is different? if you have "attribute":"value" then after parse you get value with object.attribute.

Comment: Well I wanted to parse to get the object.attribute, but my printed json has a different form

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your PHP file along with a json header. I guess that should do the trick!

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
document.write(object.toString());